# EF Model Query SELECT WHERE NOT IN

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

It's a rather simple query but I can't seem to get it done in EF.

The C# equivalent of:

```
SELECT A1, A2 from TABLEA WHERE A3 NOT IN ( SELECT B1 FROM TABLEB WHERE ... ) 
   AND A4 IN ( SELECT C2 FROM TABLEC WHERE .... )
```

I would prefer to have the query run on the database as `tableB` has `> 5000000` rows so performance is a big factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

```
var b1s = from b in TableB
          where ...
          select b.B1;

var c2s = from c in TableC
          where ...
          select c.C2;

var a1sAndA2s = from a in TableA
                where !b1s.Contains(a.A3)
                   && c2s.Contains(a.A4)
                select new {
                    a.A1,
                    a.A2
                };
```

To see the SQL statement being generated you can either use the SQL statement tracer (don't quote me on the name but it's built into VS2010) or grab the statement as a `String` via

```
String sqlStatement = (a1sAndA2s as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there another version that's more efficient perhaps ? tableB has > 5000000 rows so would prefer to have the query run on the db if possible

Comment: @Kumar Why wouldn't this execute entirely against the database? LINQ execution is deferred.

Comment: would like to make sure this is not happening on the client! is there a toll/process to debug/identify the actual queries sent to db ?

Comment: @Kumar When `a1sAndA2s` gets enumerated at runtime, it will generate one single SQL statement similar to yours. All three queries exist as expression trees until they are enumerated (in a `foreach` loop or by calling `a1sAndB2s.ToList()`, for example). At that point, Entity Framework will build a well optimized SQL statement and run it against your SQL Server instance! Neat eh?

Comment: @Kumar see my answer again for how to see the actual queryy that will be run against the server.